# Multiple problems while installing Ubuntu 13.04 on LENOVO G500 laptop

Tags: 13.04, system-installation, radeon, lenovo

***Dear Community,***

I encountered several problems when installing Ubuntu on my new Lenovo G500 laptop. First I bumped in the problem (also reported by many other) of the black screen after booting Ubuntu. This problem I recould solve by changing the "quiet splash" record of GRUB to "nomodeset".
Ubuntu install was successful then. After the installation, I had a black screen again when booting up for the first time. I booted up again with "nomodeset", and enabled the external AMD driver at Hardware Drivers. Booting still do not worked (only with nomodeset), and when I log in, the system gives me a "System program problem detected" message, and the system (desktop) does not load in.

Please, can you advise me what to do?
Shall I re-install Ubuntu?
What are the steps to make my ubuntu work with this harver?

Hardware:
LENOVO G500 with
IntelCore i5-3230M 3,2Ghz processor
and AMD Radeon HD8570 integrated chip

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: the only answer does not work for trusty, can anyone give pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

The screen brightness is set to FF, which translates to '0 brightness.' Simply press the f12 key to brighten the screen. This will need to be done every time. Alternatively, you can run this command on startup-

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
```

-where 00 is full brightness and FF is zero brightness. Luckily, I only wasted an hour figuring out how to get it to load and work.

To boot to USB, you must hold 'fn' at the lenovo boot screen, press 'f12' to see boot device options, then select the USB drive you wish to boot from. You do not need to do nomodeset.